# TFS - Team Query Not Updating For Other Users

Tags: tfs

I've added a team query that all members see. However, I made some updates to the query that are not reflected in other member's copy and can't figure out how to get the query updated on their copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try having them close and reopen their team explorer. I've noticed that it sometimes takes a little while for things that it considers to need to change less (like query definitions) to propogate. This is also true between the VS plug in for tfs and the web version.

Comment: This was on the right path. It turns out there's a refresh button in the Team Explorer pane that will refresh the queries.